# How to run a While statement inside of a While statement to fetch values from a database?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysql

Here is my function:

```
        $result_display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT $y, 20");
        $result_comment = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Comments");


while($row_display = mysql_fetch_array($result_display)){
    echo "<div id='id'" . $row_display['ID'] . " class='eventdiv' data-sort='".$row_display['TimeStamp']."'>".$row_display['Title']." TIME: ".$row_display['TimeStamp']."</div>";

    while($row_comment = mysql_fetch_array($result_comment)){
        echo $row_comment['com_details'];
    }

}
```

The HTML output is similar to this:

```
<div id='id12' class='eventdiv' data-sort='238781>Time: 238781</div>
<div id='id13' class='eventdiv' data-sort='238784>Time: 238784</div>
<div id='id14' class='eventdiv' data-sort='238785>Time: 238785</div>
<div id='id15' class='eventdiv' data-sort='238789>Time: 238789</div>
<div id='id16' class='eventdiv' data-sort='238791>Time: 238791</div>
<div id='id17' class='eventdiv' data-sort='238795>Time: 238795</div>

These are the comment details...
```

But I would like the output to be like this:

```
<div id='id12' class='eventdiv' data-sort='238781>Time: 238781</div>

These are the comment details...

<div id='id13' class='eventdiv' data-sort='238784>Time: 238784</div>

These are the comment details...

<div id='id14' class='eventdiv' data-sort='238785>Time: 238785</div>

These are the comment details...

<div id='id15' class='eventdiv' data-sort='238789>Time: 238789</div>

These are the comment details...

<div id='id16' class='eventdiv' data-sort='238791>Time: 238791</div>

These are the comment details...

<div id='id17' class='eventdiv' data-sort='238795>Time: 238795</div>

These are the comment details...
```

I thought that the way I have a while statement inside of a while statement it would display it like the HTML above, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

After you run through your $result_comment results the first time, you have to reset it with `mysql_data_seek( $result_comment )`. So:

```
while($row_display = mysql_fetch_array($result_display)){
    echo "<div id='id'" . $row_display['ID'] . " class='eventdiv' data-sort='".$row_display['TimeStamp']."'>".$row_display['Title']." TIME: ".$row_display['TimeStamp']."</div>";

    while($row_comment = mysql_fetch_array($result_comment)){
        echo $row_comment['com_details'];
    }

    mysql_data_seek( $result_comment );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run a query for each element in the first `while` loop. Currently, there's nothing that associates the comments with each event:

`$result_comment = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE [id]=$id");`

Answer (score 0):

@DemianBrecht, I am going to associate the two tables I just have not done so yet. There doesn't need to be an association to get what I need-
@Jed, I'm not sure why but the solution you proposed is producing this error:

```
'Wrong parameter count for mysql_data_seek()'
```

I found out why it was not working, the second fetch function needed to be placed inside of the first's while statement. Otherwise, it will just execute once it is completed:

```
    $result_display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT $y, 20");

while($row_display = mysql_fetch_array($result_display)){
    echo "<div id='id'" . $row_display['ID'] . " class='eventdiv' data-sort='".$row_display['TimeStamp']."'>".$row_display['Title']." TIME: ".$row_display['TimeStamp']."</div>";

    while($row_comment = mysql_fetch_array($result_comment)){

       $result_comment = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Comments");
       echo $row_comment['com_details'];

    }

}
```

Simple enough.

Comment: I would strongly recommend going with my solution so you're not making new queries to the database every time. Maybe all you needed was this: `mysql_data_seek( $result_comment, 0 )`